# How to find the last monday's data only from a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe that contains 1 years of weekly OHLC data.
What do I need ?

- list only the last monday's data of each month. For example,  May has 5 weeks and I want to list the last monday's data of may and need to discard the rest. Here's the code that I tried and I'm able to list the data on weekly basis. I got stuck here!
  Any help would be appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta

periods=pd.date_range(start='2021-4-30',periods=60,freq='W')

start = periods[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
end = periods[-1].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
symbol="^NSEI"
df=yf.download(symbol,start,end,interval="1wk",index=periods)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use groupby([pd.Grouper()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html)) to group by month and get the latest record.

```
# reset index to flatten columns
df = df.reset_index()
# copy date column to label last monday of a month
df['last_monday_of_month'] = df['Date']
# groupby month and get latest record
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M', key='Date')).last().reset_index()
```

Comment: That was helpful thanks! A quick follow up question. What if my data frame is daily data ? How do I locate only the mondays of the last week in a given range?

Comment: Here in this case, as it was monthly, by using .last() we could switch to the previous week. But with daily data, can't use last() but need to offset right?